# What means Php-Error: '/'?

Tags: php, magento, logging, magento-1.5, php-5.4

I've got the following Php-Error in my `var/log/error.php` and a blank page:

```
0.28490996360779: /
```

If I reload my page I get the similar error but with a changed number:

```
0.17993092536926: /
```

So the number seams to be a kind of id.

I work on a Magento system. The Magento logs (`system.log` as well as `exception.log`) don't show anything but they are working fine (checked it).

I'm really lost with this number/error. What does it mean?

Comment: is your Magento working fine? when are you getting this error?

Comment: @Muk no it is not. When I try to access the Magento instance I get this error and blank page.

Comment: are you using any extension which require ioncube?

Comment: @Muk no I don't think so. In this case the answer of nl-x was correct. Thanks anyway for your efforts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first guess is that some script is logging the time that it has taken to run a specific part of it, using the php function [error_log()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php).

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable developer mode
Open .htaccess and add the following line at the end

```
SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE "true"
```